# Scroll list inside of tab, so that part above tab is hidden

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-tabhost

I have TabHost and List inside one of tabs.
Above TabHost I have some info, which will be shown. So when I want to scroll down list, that info have to be hidden, and only tabs are visible. (like in AppStore).
How to realize this?

Comment: please post your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:isScrollContainer="true" 
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/label2"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"

    android:layout_below="@id/label2"/>
       <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:hint="Enter Name"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText"
    android:text="Phone Number:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>


         <EditText
          android:id="@+id/EditText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/TextView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:hint="Enter Digits"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

          <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText1"
    android:text="Email ID:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>
          <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView4"
    android:hint="Enter Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />


           <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText2"
    android:text="Address Line1:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>


           <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView5"
    android:hint="Address 1"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>

         <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText3"
    android:text="Address Line2:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>

             <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView6"
    android:hint="Address 2"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>

            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText4"
    android:text="Country"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>

             <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spin1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView7"
    android:hint="Country"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>

             <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/Spin1"
    android:text="City"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>

           <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spin2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView8"
    android:hint="city"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>


              <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/Spin2"
    android:text="State"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>

            <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spin3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView9"
    android:hint="State"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>


             <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/Spin3"
    android:text="Zip Code"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#00005c"/>

           <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView10"
    android:hint="Zip Code"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="top"/>


            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/EditText5"
    android:text="Notes:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

    android:textColor="#00005c"/>


             <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView11"
    android:hint="Notes"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="top"/>

          <Button
           android:id="@+id/Save"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@id/EditText6"
          android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
              android:text="Submit"
           android:gravity="center" 
           android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:typeface="monospace"
         android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/big_button" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

         <Button
           android:id="@+id/reset"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/Save"
           android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
           android:text="Reset"
           android:gravity="center" 
           android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
           android:typeface="monospace"
           android:textSize="22sp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
           android:background="@drawable/big_button" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


             </RelativeLayout>
             </ScrollView>
```